# Check if variable is set in PHP

Tags: php

So I'm trying to see if the user inputted anything:

```
$test = $_GET["restaurantName"];

if(isset($test))
{
    echo "you inputed something";
    echo "$test";
}

if(!isset($test))
{
    echo "you did not input anything";
    echo "$test";
}

die("The End");
```

For some reason even when I don't input anything it still passes the first if statement and says that something has been inputted even when I don't I looked up the documentation about `isset()` and I'm pretty sure that this is how you are supposed to use it.

Comment: Test the original variable i.e. `if (isset($_GET["restaurantName"]))` thats what you are interested in being set to something afterall

Comment: also i wouldn't make a habit of placing variables in a string (especially if it serves no purpose at all) echo $test; works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it this way if you want to keep the same layout style.

```
if(isSet($_GET["restaurantName"])) {
     $test = $_GET["restaurantName"];
}

if(isset($test))
    {
        echo "you inputed something";
        echo "$test";
    } else { //!isset($test)
        echo "you did not input anything";
        echo "$test";
    }
```

Your problem is that you are setting the variable, even if the GET doesn't exist.

How I would do it personally, as it makes the code much shorter with the same outputs:

```
if(isSet($_GET["restaurantName"])) {
    $test = $_GET["restaurantName"];
    echo "Your input: ".$test;
} else {
    echo "No Input";
}
```

Comment: Well you dont really need `$test` at all if you think about this logically

Comment: @RiggsFolly correct, but I like to keep shorter variable names. I wouldn't really want to type `$_GET["restaurantName"]` every time I needed that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting it: `$test = $_GET["restaurantName"];`
the isset checks whether a variable has been set, not whether the variable contained is null or empty, you could use `!empty`

you can also check `isset($_GET["restaurantName"];)` but beware even if you have the get variable in your url as `?restaurantName=` than it's still set, it's just empty

Best thing to do would be to check if it's set and not an empty string:

```
if(isset($_GET["restaurantName"]) && $_GET["restaurantName"] != "")
{
    echo "you inputed something";
    echo $_GET["restaurantName"];
} else {
    echo "you did not input anything";
}

die("The End");
```

i also removed the second if, cause you can just use an else clause instead of checking twice.

Some links to read:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Beware "!empty" condition... value "0" is considered as "empty"

Comment: true, but in case of a restaurant name i don't mind not allowing 0 as a restaurant name ;) but you're right.

Comment: @Random It's a weak reason though from my side though :p i edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If this `$_GET['restaurantName']` comes from a submitted (GET) form input rather than a query string in a link (which may or may not be present), it will always be set. If the user did not enter anything, it will be set to an empty string. You can check it using `empty` instead of `isset` (`empty` includes a check for `isset`).

```
if (!empty($_GET['restaurantName'])) {
    echo "you input " . $_GET['restaurantName'];
} else {
    echo "you did not input anything";
}
```

It may be a good idea to also check the trimmed entry in case it is something like `'   '`, which you can do with

```
if (!empty($_GET['restaurantName']) && trim($_GET['restaurantName'])) { ...
```

But that is starting to get more into form validation, which is another topic in itself.